# Move data from one database to another over ODBC

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlite, odbc

Let say, I am connected to two different databases (one SQLite and one Oracle) over ODBC in one program. Is it possible to execute a query on one database and insert the resultset as a new table in the second database directly by just passing something like a data cursor, i.e. without the hurdle to create insert statements with explicit values from the result set and executing those on the destination database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware you cannot do that. You can use something like a join engine to do it (e.g., http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc_odbc_join_engine/index.html) but it might be overkill if you are doing it just the once.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Oracle then you can use Oracle Heterogeneous Services which can work with ODBC sources. Have a look at: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_heterogeneous_database_connections_sql_server.htm